# How to add an email to an international Spam Blacklist

Tags: spam, blacklist

I am sick and tired of getting invitation emails from LinkedIn. When I ask the senders to stop sending these to me, the answer is always the same: they never sent the email in the first place.

This leads me to believe that LinkedIn is unknowingly raiding people's address books and sending out unsolicited invitations.

Is there a way to get `invitations@linkedin.com` put on a universal blacklist so these emails can stop ending up in my mailboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it might be annoying. Still the answer to your question is: **No.** You cannot just add a huge company to a block list based on your own opinions. Someone actually *wants* to get email from LinkedIn. Nor is there any list that is The Spam Blacklist that would solve the problem.

You need to make the configuration locally on your server. Since you haven't provided any information about your server configuration and even the software used, we cannot help you with specific instructions.

Anyway, I discourage making any server wide blocking if you aren't absolutely sure that none of your users is willing to receive email from LinkedIn. Best way to handle this is to use personal filters:

- On Unix/Linux systems you can add filters using e.g. Procmail or Spamassassin.
- On Exchange Server environments you can add filters in Outlook or OWA.

Which actually makes this more relevant on Super User than Server fault...

Answer (score 1):

If your email is behind exchange server and have spam filtering system, you can block emails from that email but this will effect the whole organisation. 
Unfortunately, you can't put it on a universal blacklist and you don't want to do so either as there will be thousands of people waiting for an email from linkedin invitations.

Or you may just mark email from this email addresses as spam in your outlook or mail client.